# Windows 8/RT/Store TextBox - update text binding after each key stroke

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, windows-store-apps

Is there any way to update the text binding after each key stroke?

My WPF custom TextBox uses the KeyUp event

```
private void MyTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    BindingExpression BE = GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    if (BE != null)
        BE.UpdateSource();
}
```

but `BindingExpression` doesn't exist in **Windows 8/RT/Store**.

Comment: There are some good answers below. Please mark one of them as your accepted solution.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is a little older, but I ran into this problem today and found a very simple solution.
Maybe it helps someone:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding BindingSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

With the UpdateSourceTrigger-Property set to "PropertyChanged" the UpdateSource()-method is called every time the text changes (even if the focus is not lost).

Comment: This is Windows 8.1 only. The original question was posted for Windows 8 and the lack of the `UpdateSourceTrigger` or `GetBindingExpression` APIs was acknowledged as a (dreadful) bug and fixed. Effectively, as of 2014, this is the best/proper answer, i.e. convert to 8.1.

Comment: Oh, didn't know this is only available in Win 8.1 - Thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, are you sure the text is binded properly?  Make sure the object you binded to has the INotifyPropertyChanged interface inherited and that you are calling the public string property which a NotifyProperty() event.

So then if you have everything properly binded, you can simply set the TextBox Text and the XAML will automatically update the value.

Here is a tutorial on databinding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: Of course it's bound correctly. I just want the bound property in the VM to be updated (and acted upon) after every change / key stroke, rather than having to wait until the TextBox loses focus. As I said, it's a relatively straightforward task in WPF, but Windows 8 is lacking in so many features.

Comment: So then just set the text on the TextChanged event?

Comment: If I wanted to write endless code behind event handlers, I wouldn't be using MVVM ...

Comment: Endless code? It's literally 1 line:
TextBox.TextChanged +=(o,e)=>{text = TextBox.Text;}

Answer (score 1):

You should use `TextChanged` rather than `KeyUp` or `KeyDown`

[How to immediately update the source of a TextBox in WinRT with C#](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/how-to-immediately-update-the-source-of-a-textbox-in-winrt/)

Answer (score 1):

There is way to solve your issue using attached properties. Check [How To Make TextBox.Text Work](http://www.inexika.com/blog/textbox-text-how-to) article.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a way to accomplish this task, that would be easier on other versions of **Silverlight** (WPF and Windows Phone *in primis*)...

There's no `BindingExpression` for **Windows RT/Store applications**, as you can see!...

Implements this code, compatible with you *MVVM pattern*...

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace YourProject
{
    public static class TextBoxEx
    {
        public static string GetRealTimeText(TextBox obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(RealTimeTextProperty);
        }

        public static void SetRealTimeText(TextBox obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(RealTimeTextProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RealTimeTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RealTimeText", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxEx), null);

        public static bool GetIsAutoUpdate(TextBox obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsAutoUpdateProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsAutoUpdate(TextBox obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsAutoUpdateProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAutoUpdateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsAutoUpdate", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxEx), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsAutoUpdateChanged));

        private static void OnIsAutoUpdateChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textbox = (TextBox)sender;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                textbox.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
            else
                textbox.TextChanged -= textbox_TextChanged;
        }

        private static void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textbox = (TextBox)sender;

            textbox.SetValue(TextBoxEx.RealTimeTextProperty, textbox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

...and then just use it in your XAML, with a small trick (a double binding), as shown below...

1) Declare the new "utility" class:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="YourProject.YourPage"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="YourProject"
    ...
    xmlns:extra="using:YourProject.YourNameSpace"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

2) Implementation in your controls:

```
<TextBox extra:TextBoxEx.IsAutoUpdate="True"
         extra:TextBoxEx.RealTimeText="{Binding Path=YourTextProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="YourTextProperty"
                 Mode="OneWay" />
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This worked fine for me, I hope can help you!